# headphones sound not working with hp spectre x360

Tags: sound, laptop, hp, headphones

I have "hp spectre x360" laptop and I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on it

the sound work great with the speakers but not with headphones

I need help, please

Comment: Same problem with fedora 27-28. No sound with headphones(checked several headphones, output is NOT muted). Tried everything - hopeless.